# Using custom Angular Material Sort?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to create a dropdown (or mat-select) to use as a sorting mechanism instead of the Angular Material Sort Header. So, if I for example click on the 'username' inside the dropdown, I want the table to sort by the username (instead of clicking on the header).

[image]

How can I do it? Any documentation online on how to achieve this?

Thank you for any help.

As required, I attach some code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.providersAdmin.sort = this.sort;
  }

  getAllAdmins() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.homeService.getAllAdmins().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.admins = response;
          this.providersAdmin = new MatTableDataSource(this.admins);
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      (error) => {}
    );
  }

  sortTableBy(event: any) {
    const sortState: Sort = {
      active: "username",
      direction: "desc",
    };
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);

    console.log(event);
  }
```

The sortTableBy method is the one I found on [here](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/custom-sort-javascript-tables/) but nothing happens.

I added matSort on the mat-table and I added mat-sort-header on the header cell.

**EDIT:**
Hi, I managed to fix the problem by writing the following:

```
sortTableBy(event: any) {
    const sortState: Sort = {
      active: "username",
      direction: "desc",
    };
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);
    this.providersAdmin.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code

Comment: Well, basically nothing because I don't know how to start. I did use this tutorial https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/custom-sort-javascript-tables/, and I managed to catch the emit to the MatSort but it didn't update my table.

Actually, let me add the code in the main thread for what I have currently.

Comment: A tip - here is the source of `sort` function that `MatSort` uses https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sort/sort.ts#L152

Comment: @SOverfow Yeah I assumed that I would have to dig inside the source to find the source of what messed the sort... Will do!

Comment: Hi, I tried to fix this for a long time until I realized that I just have to reset the new Admins after the sort inside the sortTableBy method.

I will post the solution in the OP.

Now it works, If anyone else has the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to set up an example which you can adapt easily:

```
  compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
  }

  sortData() {
    let isAsc = this.sort.direction != "" ? 
      event.direction == SortDirection.asc : 
      true;
    let data = this.dataSource.data.slice();
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      switch (this.myChosenSort) {
        case 'healthCareCenterName':
          return this.compare(a.healthCareCenterName, b.healthCareCenterName, isAsc);
        case 'address':
          return this.compare(a.address, b.address, isAsc);
        case 'contact':
          return this.compare(a.contact, b.contact, isAsc);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ServiceProviderTable>(data);
  }
```

To change the sort.direction you need to play around a little bit with the code, maybe directly from the dropdown and hardcoding the isAsc when calling the compare method, depending on the value of the this.myChosenSort.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for you:
[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mltdz6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Your sort function has a wrong implementation, this is work for me:

```
  sortData(fieldName: string) {
    if (!fieldName) {
      return;
    }

    const sortState: MatSortable = {
      id: fieldName,
      start: 'desc',
      disableClear: true
    };
    this.sort.sort(sortState);
  }
```

Comment: Don't answer with just a link and no explanation: paste the important pieces of code in your answer and explain the idea.

Comment: OP is using Angular Material tables with MatSort directive. Not a "simple array".

Comment: @GaëlJ my first version was written before the author's code preview. So now I implemented right solution :)